# Run with console class import error(java)

Tags: java

The question is: if I run my `Test.java` file with run button in IntelliJ it works just fine, but if I run it manually with console by writing `java Test.java` it breaks with an error. (Files are in the same folder.):

> Error

```
.\src\Test.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        Car car1 = new Car();
        ^
  symbol:   class Car
  location: class Test
.\src\Test.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        Car car1 = new Car();
```

> Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car1 = new Car();
        System.out.println(car1.model);
    }
}
```

> Car.java

```
public class Car {
    String model = "Corvette";
}
```

Comment: Compile first, then run: `javac Test.java` then `java Test`. I don't know the precise rules for what running `java` with a source file are, but it looks like they're limited compared with the more traditional "compile to class files first" approach.

Comment: "Car"1 is not initially static, remove the two lines from main method and put them in the/a "public Test" constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `java` command that appears in the *Run* window of IntelliJ when you run class `Test`. You will notice it is very different to that which you are trying, i.e. `java Test.java`.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html), you can only run a single source code file, however class `Test` references class `Car` so you need to first compile class `Car` and then add the appropriate *path* option, i.e. either `--class-path` or `--module-path`, e.g.

```
java --class-path whatever Test.java
```

where *whatever* is the appropriate path to file `Car.class`.

Alternatively, when running a single Java source code file, the file name does **not** have to be identical to the name of the public class that it defines and it can also contain more than one public class – contrary to the rules required when compiling Java source code. (Refer to the documentation for [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html) as well as Oracle's Java [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html).) Hence you can write the code for both class `Car` and class `Test` in a single file and run that code using the `java` command.

I wrote file `TestCar.java` as follows:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car1 = new Car();
        System.out.println(car1.model);
    }
}

public class Car {
    String model = "Corvette";
}
```

And issued the following command, from the folder containing file `TestCar.java`:

```
java TestCar.java
```

And got the following output:

```
Corvette
```

I used [Oracle] JDK 19 on Windows 10.